# how to pass values in CGAffineTransformMake

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

I want to set the custom coordinate to crop video.But i don't know how to set the x and y value in this or how to pass values in the function

```
CGAffineTransformMake(CGFloat a, CGFloat b, CGFloat c, CGFloat d,
  CGFloat tx, CGFloat ty)
```

I searched everywhere but everyone is saying that it creates a matrix in the background,but i have nothing to do with the matrix, i just want to set the values of `X and Y.`
Can anyone please suggest me the correct explanation with example.It would be a great help for me.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: An Affine Transfrom __is__ a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(give what scale you want,give what scale you want)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This function just zoom on the particular(by default) region,but is it possible to  zoom on particular part of video which we specify???